# Populating html table with database data through user selection in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, filter

So, I have a checkbox that allows the user to select the columns they want to view. So, if the user wants for example to select only 2 columns (say, TicketID and Category) it will only show the data of the ID and the category of the ticket. Here's what I have so far:

form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="TicketID" >Ticket ID</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Category" />Category</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Priority" />Priority</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Status" />Status</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="InitialDescription" />Initial Description</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="SubmittedDate" />Submitted Date</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Description" />Status Description</li>
        <input type="submit" value="Refresh Filters">
    </ul>
</form>
</td>
<td>
    <?php 


    viewTicketTable($_SESSION['userID'],$_POST['filter']);

        ?>
```

viewticketTable function:

```
function viewTicketTable($userID,$columns) {
/* Accepts $userID which will identify the tickets related with the user and
$columns which will filter only the columns that are required and outputs the
table with the columns passed through. */


/* 
$columns_array = explode(',', $columns);

foreach($array as $array){
    echo $array;
} */


foreach($columns as $filter) {
    $filter = $filter  . ',' ;

}

$filter = substr($filter, 0, -1);   


$query = mysql_query("
SELECT $filter
FROM Ticket
LEFT JOIN TicketHistory
ON Ticket.TicketID = TicketHistory.TicketID
WHERE CustomerID = $userID;
");



/* Creation of the table */
echo '
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>';
            foreach($columns as $tableHeader) {
                $tableHeader = '<th scope="col">' . $tableHeader  . '</th>' ;
                echo $tableHeader;
            }
echo '
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
';

/*Looping through the script to print out all the information.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
    echo '
            <tr>';
                foreach($columns as $field) {
                    echo '<td>' . $row[$field] . '</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr>
    ';
}


echo '  </tbody>
    </table>';
```

}

The problem resides in the while loop. row[$field] is only populating the last column instead of populating all of them. Any help?

Comment: Before anything else; you need to do something to harden your query against SQL injection.  Right now anyone with enough chops to use a browser to inspect and edit your page could change one of the filter input values to something malicious.

Comment: right now I just wanted it to work... But thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL syntax - you have an extra `;` before the `"` closes

Also, you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` in place of `mysql_fetch_array` as using `mysql_fetch_array` without specifying a method is going to return a double array.

Comment: I tried this: `function test($userID, $columns) {

 foreach($columns as $filter) {
  $filter = $filter  . ',' ;
  
 }
 
 $filter = substr($filter, 0, -1);

 $query = mysql_query("
 SELECT $filter
 FROM Ticket
 LEFT JOIN TicketHistory
 ON Ticket.TicketID = TicketHistory.TicketID
 WHERE CustomerID = $userID
 ");
 
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die(mysql_error());
 print_r($row);
}` and it returned : Array ( [Priority] => 3 )

Is it a sql mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I'll post the answer in case someone has the same issue.

The problem was fixed here:

```
    $filter = "";
foreach($columns as $c) {
    $filter = $filter . $c  . ',' ;

}

$filter = substr($filter, 0, -1);
```

The loop was not assigning the values to the $filter variable so I had to create an external variable. There was also anther error in the foreach loop that I had to fix with an if statement (not the best way of doin it, but it works):

```
foreach($columns as $field) {
if ($field == 'Ticket.TicketID'){
    $field = 'TicketID';
}
echo '<td>' . $row[$field] . '</td>';
}
```

Ticket.TicketID wasn't accepted in the $row array, so I had to change it to TicketID

Thanks everyone for the help anyway.